# Find indefinable set that is included in definable set.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Find $K\subseteq \operatorname{Ass} $ and $ K'\subseteq K$  such that $K$ is definable but $K'$ is not.

**Definition (Definable)**: a set $K$ of assignments is definable if there is a set of formulas A such that $\operatorname{Ass}(A) = K$.

Comment: What does $\mathit{Ass}$ mean here? And which particular kind of "formulas" are you looking at? What is an "assignment" in this context?

Comment: Yes, it seems you are using "Ass" in two contexts: first as a set ($K\subseteq \text{ Ass}$), and then as a function/operator ($\operatorname{Ass}(A) = K$). Please clarify.

Comment: I apologize, Ass is the set of all assignments. assignment is defined on variables Pi to {t,f}, and i is natural number. Is it clear? @JordanGlen

Comment: @HenningMakholm I wrote clarification in the comment

Comment: When you write "Pi" do you mean $P_i$ or $\Pi$ -- and anyway, what _is_ that? Is $(x\mapsto \mathsf t)$ an "assignment", or does it need to be an entire $\{x\mapsto \mathsf t,y\mapsto \mathsf f,z\mapsto \cdots\}$ (that is, a total function $\Pi\to\{\mathsf t,\mathsf f\}$ for some yet-to-be-determined $\Pi$)? And what does $\mathit{Ass}(A)$ mean?

Comment: "Pi" mean variable $Pi$ as you wrote in the first option. $Ass(A)$ is the set of assignments that satifies the set of formulas A. Is it clear now? I don't know the English terminology well, I apologize @HenningMakholm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** $K=\mathit{Ass}$ is definable, so all you need to do is find *some* non-definable set of assignments.

You need to involve infinitely many propositional variable, because every truth functional of *finitely* many variables can be defined by a single formula.

How about the set of all possible assignments *except* the one that makes every propositional variable false?

Comment: I need to find K that is not the whole $Ass$

Comment: @CnR: But in the question you explicitly wrote $K\subseteq \mathit{Ass}$, not $K\subset\mathit{Ass}$ or $K\subsetneq\mathit{Ass}$. Very well, though -- let $K$ be those assignments that make $P_0$ false, and still let $K'$ be those assignments from $K$ that at least make _something_ true.